# How to match validation that's 7 numbers OR 9 numbers long using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, function, validation, passwords

Current code

```
var codePattern = /^\d{7,9}$/;
```

Basically I want:

1 – 6 digits = NO

7 digits = YES
8 digits = NO

9 digits = YES

greater= 10 digits = NO…!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
var codePattern = /^\d{7}(?:\d{2})?$/;
```

Which basically matches 7 digits at the start and then it is followed by 2 optional digits in the end `(?:\d{2})?` thus enabling it to `match either 7 digits or 9 digits`.

Comment: No that can't be. `/^\d{7}(?:\d{2})?$/.test('12345678');` returns false

Comment: Just curious, why the non-capturing group?

Comment: @Ejay: Yeah non-capturing group is not really needed.

Comment: Just a website I'm working on. They only want to use validation codes that are either 7 or 9 numbers long. no idea why tbh.

Comment: Ok apologies, I've just tried it again and it's worked! :) thanks

Comment: @anubhava your edit has made it invalid. Now it doesn't validate 7 digit strings in firefox.  
`var codePattern = /^\d{7}\d{2}?$/;  
codePattern.test('1234567');`
`var codePattern = /^\d{7}(\d{2})?$/;` is probably right.

Comment: @Ejay: Oh ok rolled back my change.

Comment: @Hoyesic: problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: I've tested in all the browsers and it works fine. Sorry I'm pretty new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of options. For example

```
/^\d{7}|\d{9}$/
/^\d{7}\d{2}?$/
```

Comment: the second one is failing for a 7 digit string.

Answer (score 0):

Should do it:

```
 /^(\d{7}|\d{9})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `/^\d{7}(\d\d)?$/` or `/^[0-9]{7}[0-9]{2}?$/`